# Using Latex systeme package with subscripted variables as well as parameters

Tags: systeme

I am trying to use the CTAN systeme package with

```
\systeme{ x_0 + 2x_1 + 4x_2 = 1,x_1 - 9x_2 = -2,( 9 k - 36 ) x_2 = h + 2 k - 10}
```

As written, it does not properly recognize the variables `x_0, x_1, x_2`
due to the presence of the parameter `k`
`\systeme[x]{...}` does not work in this case.

How do I specify the variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell `\systeme` what are the unknowns and to mask the minus sign in the coefficient.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\systeme[x_0x_1x_2]{
  x_0 + 2x_1 + 4x_2 = 1,
  x_1 - 9x_2 = -2,
  ( 9 k \- 36 ) x_2 = h + 2 k - 10
}

\end{document}
```

[image]